# "Validation of viewstate MAC failed" on postback to a different page

Tags: asp.net-3.5, postback, viewstate

I'm working on a web form which works fine as long as it posts back to itself. In Reports.aspx I have:

```
<form runat="server" method="post">
```

but, when I try to get it to post to a different page:

```
<form runat="server" method="post" action="DisplayReport.aspx">
```

I get the "Validation of viewstate MAX failed" error. I've tried setting the machine key and disabling the viewstate in web.config, but nothing seems to help. Am I stuck posting back to the same page? If so what is the point of the action attribute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can submit to a different page, but you need to use the [`PostBackUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) property of a button, not the form's `action` attribute.

Instead of this:

```
<form runat="server" method="post" action="DisplayReport.aspx">
    <!-- form stuff goes here -->
    <asp:button runat="server" text="Submit" />
</form>
```

Do this:

```
<form runat="server">
    <!-- form stuff goes here -->
    <asp:button runat="server" text="Submit" postbackurl="DisplayReport.aspx" />
</form>
```

Comment: this still doesn't explain what's the point of Action attribute?

Comment: you saved my day, hats off to you

Answer (score 0):

Cross page post backs should be available, you just have to set them up as so.  See this link http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/08/cross-page-posting-in-aspnet.html